# iOS push Notification SSL Revoked

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, push-notification

I have implemented the Push Notification and uploaded the build to AppStore. The notifications are coming fine on Development, but are not coming from production, I found there was a issue in `.pem` file I have generated for the production. Unfortunately I lost my private key for the production `SSL` certificate, therefore I can't generate the same `.pem` file for the same certificate without the private key. Now I must have to revoke the old certificate with the new one.

My Question is that. Do I have to upload the new build on AppStore after revoking the certificate? I created the new certificate but it seems Notifications are not coming on production still.

Should I have to upload the build??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create a new provisioning profile with the new certificate and need to submit the build again with that new provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

No i don't want that you should upload a new build please check first the new certificate. If there is problem that is same as previous regarding push then try to solve it. After this you should go with new certificate.

Hope this helps

Comment: how new certificate will be binded with the provisioning of app without uploading app again?

Comment: I did all things create the new certificate from scratch with SSL as welll.. but notifications are not coming from production.

Comment: I have also gone through this problem.But that time the error from server end please wait for time and send push again

Comment: I am doing this for last few days. but not getting any result. I am thinking to upload the build again.

Comment: Yeah if you want then you can go with this because it is not good to waste time on the things which you can do in another way

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to create the new certificate. The app on app store will continue to work. You need to create new certificate when you need to upload the new version of your application